# Always visible ScrollBar even if nothing to scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

The [Scrollbar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html) widget has a field 'thumbVisibility' to make the Scrollbar "always" visible. This is not true. When there is nothing to scroll, the Scrollbar disappears.

I want my Scrollbar to be always visible, even if there is nothing to scroll.

How is this possible?

A workaround for me would be to somehow check if the Scrollbar is visible. But I was unable to check this via the ScrollController.

Answer (score -2):

The `Scrollbar` class has a property called `thumbVisibility`. Make it `true`.

```
Scrollbar(
          thumbVisibility: true,
```

It'll only show when you've something to scroll, or else it'll be pointless to be visible.

Scrollbar height adjusts according to their attached widget. Right?
If there's a list of 10 items, then it will become huge.
If there's a list of 100 items, then it will become tiny.

What would be the height of the scrollbar if there's nothing to scroll?

Comment: The OP said that that prop is not working in their case.

Comment: Did you even read my question? Also, your height suggestion is completely useless as I don't know how to check the height of the scrollbar. There is no property in the ScrollController to do this.